# java - Implement Facebook login using Android Studio and Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, authentication

I've tried to use the Facebook SDK to create a simple Facebook login inside my application.
Everything works fine, but the registerCallback function of LoginButton does not work properly.
This is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            message = "Success! ";
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            message = "Cancel!";
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            message = e.getMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

This is inside my main activity.
I then proceed to print the 'message' variable which is always empty because none of the registerCallback functions seems to be executed. 
If I try to login again, Facebook says that I already enabled this application, but I did not receive feedback about the LoginResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented onActivityResult in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i was missing! Thank you :D

Comment: Cheers :) , happy coding